# Fillfdown Approach for an index match function via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

with the given code I am trying hard incorporate the Filldown approach until the last row but at present whatever I do only fills row number 1:

```
Sub FillDownApproach()
Dim destinationWs As Worksheet
Dim destinationLastRow As Long

Set destinationWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main Board")
destinationLastRow = destinationWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

RetVal = destinationWs.Evaluate("INDEX('MyData'!$E:$E,MATCH(1,($A2='MyData'!$B:$B)*(""MyItem""='MyData'!$D:$D),0))")
destinationWs.Range("C2").Value = RetVal
destinationWs.Range("C3: " & "C" & destinationLastRow).FillDown

End Sub
```

Any suggestion that could point towards the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: At this point it is going to be quicker to load all pertinent data into variant arrays, loop the arrays and load another output variant array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do what you want without looping.  And Looping ranges is slow.

Instead load Variant arrays and loop them.

```
Sub FillDownApproach()
    Dim destinationWs As Worksheet
    Set destinationWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main Board")
    
    Dim destinationLastRow As Long
    destinationLastRow = destinationWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim lkpArr As Variant
    lkpArr = destinationWs.Range("A2:A" & destinationLastRow).Value
    
    With Worksheets("MyData")
    
        Dim retval As Variant
        retval = Intersect(.Range("E:E"), .UsedRange)
        
        Dim mtch As Variant
        mtch = Intersect(.Range("B:D"), .UsedRange)
        
    End With
    
    Dim outArr As Variant
    ReDim outArr(1 To UBound(lkpArr, 1), 1 To 1)
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(lkpArr, 1)
        Dim j As Long
        For j = 1 To UBound(retval, 1)
            If mtch(j, 3) = "MyItem" Then
                If mtch(j, 1) = lkpArr(i, 1) Then
                    outArr(i, 1) = retval(j, 1)
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    
    destinationWs.Range("C2").Resize(UBound(outArr, 1), 1).Value = outArr
    
End Sub
```

Comment: what if I have multiple columns and need to perform the above? Thanks a lot

Comment: There are a lot of columns in the above code, to which are you refering?