# What is the fastest way to pull data from one sheet to another using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, vlookup

I have and excel file with 2 tabs, one is 166K rows and the other is 400K rows. Previously we were manually performing vlookups to pull data from the 400k row tab into the 166k row tab. I want to automate this some using VBA but am having issues with speed.

I tried an IF formula but that ran for over 30 minutes before I killed the process

```
 For i = 2 To Assign.UsedRange.Rows.Count
 For x = 2 To HR.UsedRange.Rows.Count

 If Assign.Cells(i, 1 ) = HR.Cells(x,1) Then
   Assign.Cells(i, 9) = HR.Cells(x, 3)
 
 End If

 Next x
 Next i
```

and now I'm trying a vlookup for VBA but that also is taking a long time.

```
 For x = 2 To Assign.UsedRange.Rows.Count

 On Error Resume Next
 Worksheets("Assignments").Cells(x, 9).Value = 
 Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Worksheets("Assignments").Cells(x, 5).Value, 
 Worksheets("Workforce").Range("A:AX"), 5, 0)
 On Error GoTo 0
   
 Next x
```

any suggestions on how to speed this up? I tried using Access but the files were too big.

Comment: Use variant arrays and loop them.  For Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68668043/fillfdown-approach-for-an-index-match-function-via-vba/68668401#68668401

Comment: Or a `Scripting.Dictionary`.

Comment: Do you have links to Scripting.Dictionary? I looked it up but only found how to create a dictionary using new data, not linking it to existing.

Answer (score 0):

I would try with the find method instead of an inner loop. You have just to customize your file references and ranges.

```
 Sub FindMatches()

    Dim shtOld As Worksheet, shtNew As Worksheet

    Dim oldRow As Integer
    Dim newRow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer, id, f As Range

    i = 1

    Set shtOld = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Assign")
    Set shtNew = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HR")
        
    For oldRow = 2 To shtOld.UsedRange.Rows.Count

        id = shtOld.Cells(oldRow, 1)

        Set f = shtNew.Range("A1:A1000").Find(id, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            With shtOld.Rows(i)
                .Cells(1).Value = shtOld.Cells(oldRow, 1)

            End With
            i = i + 1
        End If

    Next oldRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks there was a typo in my code i put on here.. shouldnt have said "Report", that should have said "Assign"

Comment: You can then change the names of the sheets with the one you have :)

Comment: getting an "overflow" error with this line " For oldRow = 2 To shtOld.UsedRange.Rows.Count"

Comment: [Use Long, not Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long).

Comment: Thanks i just removed Integer and it seemed to work... but im missing how this pulls data from the HR sheet into the Assign sheet. I see how it can find a match, but not how it writes to the assign tab.

Comment: Set shtMatch = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("report") this is the line where you define the destination sheet, if it isn't a new one just replace "report" with the sheet you want

Comment: Since the question is "**what is the fastest way...**", the answer would be complete, if you could also provide why do you think this is the fastest way.

Answer (score 0):

### A VBA Lookup

- This took roughly 13 seconds on my machine (`Windows 10, Office 2019 64bit`) for 400k vs 160k of integers.
- An optimized (using arrays and `Application.Match` applied to the lookup column range) `Match` version took the same amount of time for 10 times fewer data.
- Since your data probably isn't integers, your feedback is highly appreciated.
- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub VBALookup()

    Const sName As String = "Workforce" ' Source Worksheet Name
    Const slFirst As String = "E2" ' Source Lookup Column First Cell Address
    Const svCol As String = "I" ' Source Value Column
    
    Const dName As String = "Assignments" ' Destination Worksheet Name
    Const dlFirst As String = "E2" ' Destination Lookup First Cell Address
    Const dvCol As String = "I" ' Destination Value Column
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Create references to the Source Ranges.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = sws.Range(slFirst)
    Dim slrg As Range: Set slrg = RefColumn(sfCell) ' lookup range
    If slrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim svrg As Range: Set svrg = slrg.EntireRow.Columns(svCol) ' read value
    
    ' Create references to the Destination Ranges.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(dlFirst)
    Dim dlrg As Range: Set dlrg = RefColumn(dfCell) ' lookup value
    If dlrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim dvrg As Range: Set dvrg = dlrg.EntireRow.Columns(dvCol) ' write value

    ' Write the 'INDEX/MATCH' formula to a variable.
    Dim dFormula As String
    dFormula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('" & sName & "'!" & svrg.Address(, 0) _
        & ",MATCH(" & dfCell.Address(0, 0) _
        & ",'" & sName & "'!" & slrg.Address(, 0) & ",0)),"""")"
    
    ' Take a look in the Immediate window ('Ctrl + G')
    'Debug.Print "Source", slrg.Address(, 0), svrg.Address(, 0)
    'Debug.Print "Destination", dlrg.Address(, 0), dvrg.Address(, 0)
    'Debug.Print "Formula", dFormula
    
    ' Write the formula to the Destination Value Range
    ' and convert the formulas to values.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    dvrg.Formula = dFormula
    dvrg.Value = dvrg.Value
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to the range from the first cell
'               of a range ('rg') through the bottom-most non-empty cell
'               of the range's column.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefColumn( _
    ByVal rg As Range) _
As Range
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    With rg.Cells(1)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        Set RefColumn = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the values of a range ('rg') in a 2D one-based array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetRange( _
    ByVal rg As Range) _
As Variant
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    Dim rData As Variant
    If rg.Rows.Count + rg.Columns.Count = 2 Then
        ReDim rData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): rData(1, 1) = rg.Value
    Else
        rData = rg.Value
    End If
    GetRange = rData
End Function
```